# Changed position of fixed HTML element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if its possible to move a div or other element with "position:fixed;". I would like it to not be affected by scrolling and I'll probably set it up so you can move it with a click and drag, but I cant even get it to budge. Are "fixed" elements incapable of doing this?

```
#menu {
    position:fixed;
    margin-top: -110px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    //its now top:110px; left:300px;
}
<TABLE id="menu">
    my menu here
</TABLE>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = document.getElementById('menu');
    d.style.left =d.style.left+2;  //doesn't work
    d.style.top = '5';  // doesn't work
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
d.style.left = d.style.left + 2 + 'px'; 
d.style.top = '5px';
```

You need to specify the values units (*pixels for example*), check [**this**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) document for other units.

```js
var menu = document.getElementById('menu'); 
var unit = document.getElementById('unit');
var offset = 0;

menu.style.top = '5px';

function move(){
  offset += 20;
  menu.style.left = offset + unit.value; 
};

function reset(){
  offset = 0;
  menu.style.left = '0px'; 
};
```

```css
#menu {
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    position:fixed;
    color: white
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
    my menu here
</div>
<br/>
<span>Unit</span>
<select id="unit">
  <option value="px">px</option>
  <option value="em">em</option>
  <option value="ex">ex</option>
  <option value="%">%</option>
  <option value="cm">cm</option>
  <option value="mm">mm</option>
  <option value="in">in</option>
  <option value="pt">pt</option>
  <option value="pc">pc</option>
</select>
<br/>
<button onclick="move()">Move</button>
<button onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
<br/>
Play with "Move" and "Reset" buttons to see the difference between units
```

Comment: Ugh, of course!! Thanks a ton for the quick response.

Comment: You are welcome friend, glad to help, now updated the example you can play with the different units :)

Comment: damn I love the "Run code snippet" function, this is great @codtex

Answer (score -1):

```
try the below code, it is working for me. You can see that the 2px margin in the inline style in developer tools
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta lang="en">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<style>
  #menu {
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: 110px;
    margin-left: 300px;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <table id="menu">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td>two</td>
        <td>three</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var d = document.getElementById('menu');
    d.style.left = d.style.left + 2 + "px";
    d.style.top = '5' + "px";
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Yep, I needed the "px", I'm tempted to take the question down its a bit embarrassing ha. Thanks for your answer.